# opencti "setSoftphonePanelVisibility" has no effect if "isSoftphonePanelVisible" was invoked before

Tags: salesforce

**Background**:

In Lightning mode, when the Lightning console App is displayed, and based on a specicific message received from my 3rd-party app, I invoke `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility(true)`, the softphone is first hidden (shortly), then shown again.
As I debugged my code, I could verify, that invoking

`sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility(true)` led to this behavior.

So, I decided to first invoke 
`sforce.opencti.isSoftphonePanelVisible()`, then depending on the response in its callback, I decide to invoke 
`sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility(true)` or not.

The problem is, when I do this, `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility(true)` has then no effect, allthough the OpenCTI call is responded correctly (response.success=true and response.errors=undefined): The softphone is still minimized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any advice? Is that perhaps a known issue or so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to share how I solved (workaround) this issue.
A good functional workaround I had implemented was to first of all invoke `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility({visible:true});` in your initialization phase of the softphone. I then check the content of the GUI to be displayed. If there are calls to be display, the softphone has to remain visible. Otherwise, it will be hidden using `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility({visible:false});`.

All subsequent calls of `sforce.opencti.isSoftphonePanelVisible();` followed by `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility({visible:true});` will be functional to 100%.

It seems that OpenCTI expects that `sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelVisibility({visible:true});` is invoked first before `sforce.opencti.isSoftphonePanelVisible();`.